# Is it in python possible to call a method from a C++ dll which deallocate/reallocates memory in a struct originally created from Python?

Tags: python, c++, pointers, struct, dll

I have a dll written in C++ which I want to use from Python. The dll has a data struct with multiple fields. One of these fields is a float*. Some methods in the dll changes the size of this "array" and when this happens I get a heap error in Python.

So far, I have implemented a struct i Python using ctypes which corresponds to the struct in the dll. I can then call methods within the dll from Python using this struct.

As long as I call dll-methods that only changes fields that have a fixed length (it can be, e.g., int, float, char array with fixed length, ...) everything works fine. However, as soon as any of the methods change the size of the float* field, I get a heap error.

Is there any way I can solve this or do I always need to make sure that the float* "array" has the correct length before calling the method in the dll?

In the attached code I have simplified the struct so that it contains only a few fields but still give rises to the described problem.

**C++   MyCode.h**

```
#pragma once
#include <sal.h>

typedef struct MyStruct
{
    // the number of data points used in the array 'A'
    unsigned int    length;

    // this is a numerical value
    float    value;

    // the data array
    float*    A;
}MyStruct;

extern "C" {
    void __cdecl ChangeValue(_Inout_ MyStruct* data, float newValue);
    void __cdecl ResizeDataArray(_Inout_ MyStruct* data, unsigned int newLength);
}
```

**C++   MyCode.cpp**

```
#include <sal.h>
#include "MyCode.h"

extern "C" void __cdecl ChangeValue(_Inout_ MyStruct * data, float newValue)
{
    data->value = newValue;
}

extern "C" void __cdecl ResizeDataArray(_Inout_ MyStruct * data, unsigned int newLength)
{
    if (data == nullptr)
    {
        return;
    }

    // Resize A if a different length is desired

    if (data->length != newLength)
    {
        if (data->length > 0 && data->A != nullptr)
        {
            delete[] data->A;
            data->length = 0U;
        }

        // Allocate memory and set it to = 0

        data->A = new float[newLength];
        memset(data->A, 0, newLength * sizeof(float));

        data->length = newLength;
    }
}
```

**C++  StructTool.def**

```
LIBRARY    "StructTool"

EXPORTS
    ChangeValue
    ResizeDataArray
```

**Python code**

```
import os
import ctypes as c

class MyStruct(c.Structure):
    _fields_ = [
        ("length", c.c_uint),
        ("value", c.c_float),
        ("A", c.POINTER(c.c_float))
        ]

if __name__ == '__main__':

    dllPath = r'C:\MyFolder'
    dllFullPath = os.path.join(dllPath, 'StructTool.dll')
    if not os.path.exists(dllFullPath):
        print('DLL '+ dllFullPath +' not found')
        exit(1)

    os.chdir(dllPath)
    my_dll = c.CDLL(dllFullPath)  # Load method

    # Create a data struct

    testStruct = MyStruct()

    # Allocate the array of floats and initialize the struct

    array_size = 10
    testStruct.A = (c.c_float * array_size)()
    testStruct.length = array_size
    testStruct.value = 0.12345

    print("testStruct.length: ", testStruct.length)
    print("testStruct.value: ", testStruct.value, "\n")

    # Let's change "value" in the struct - This works fine

    my_dll.ChangeSingleValue.argtypes = [c.POINTER(MyStruct), c.c_float]
    newValue = 123.456
    my_dll.ChangeSingleValue(c.byref(testStruct), newValue)
    
    print("testStruct.value: ", testStruct.value, "\n")
    
    # Let's change the length of the A-field in the struct - THIS DOES NOT WORK!

    my_dll.ResizeDataArray.argtypes = [c.POINTER(MyStruct), c.c_uint]
    newLength = 15
    my_dll.ResizeDataArray(c.byref(testStruct), newLength)    # This is where I get the heap error

    print("testStruct.length: ", testStruct.length)
```

Comment: Don't allocate the array in Python (or C) if you plan to reallocate it in C++ with `new` and `delete`. Initialise the length to 0 and call `ResizeDataArray` instead of doing `(c.c_float * array_size)`.

Comment: In general when crossing tech boundaries let each technology manage its own memory (due to different memory models and lifetime rules). In a lot of cases I just opt to copy data from one technology to the next in an adapter layer (unless there is a real unacceptable performance issue).